# Has Java memory usage improved since JDK 6?

Tags: java, memory

My organization is currently in the process of going through a system upgrade, moving up multiple versions. Our current version runs on Java 6, while the upgraded version will run on 8. We were given new hardware sizing documents which actually call for significantly less required memory than is being currently used (down to 16GB from 28GB). When we reached out to the vendor to indicate our concerns, they stated that there had been improvements in the application, as well as in the way that Java manages memory.

I'm willing to believe that there have been some improvements in application efficiency, but this seems like a dramatic change. Is it true that there have been significant improvements in Java memory management from v6 to v8?

Comment: Are you talking about 3rd party software memory requirements reducing over time? If so, this is nothing usual - maybe their early versions were thrown together to get to market and later they improved their implementation using the funds raised from licences. By the way, even if you update to java 8, you’ll only be 4 years behind the times instead of 12 years.

Comment: the application != the JVM.

Comment: GC has improved. but probably most of the memory savings was from fixing outrageously bad code that was wasting memory. hey, it's a vendor application. don't know how you can get a more precise answer.

Comment: I guess I'm primarily asking if garbage collection has gotten any better, or if there's anything inherently different in those two versions (7&8) that would reduce memory utilization.

Comment: In short, improvements to the JVM wouldn’t mean that much less memory used for the same application.

Comment: Yes, you may see great improvements on heap sizes because interned strings and classes metadata are stored on native memory rather than on the perm space.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that, in Java 9+, `String`s can be encoded using Latin1 instead of UTF-16. This results in less memory required when not using *special* characters in `String`s.

Comment: @Bohemian Java 8 *is* the most current LTS, by the way.

Comment: @chrylis but it is also ending soon; the next LTS version is 11, which already exists.

Comment: TBH, if they don't point you to specific improvements in which Java manages memory that benefit their application, then it's likely a way of deflecting from the fact that their application was using far too much memory to begin with, and most of the improvements will have come from improving the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 6, a `String` used a shared `char[]` with `offset` and `count` into the array, such that `substring` didn't have to copy the `char[]`.

That was a premature optimization, and reality showed that many programs would load a big string, the create a few substrings and store those, cause the entire big string it stay in memory.

In **Java 7**, they eliminated the shared `char[]`, improving memory use for many program. Some program might however use more memory. It depends on how strings are used. See e.g. "[The substring() Method in JDK 6 and JDK 7](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/)".

It was still found that `String` objects was by far the single biggest consumer of memory in most programs, so that has been addressed:

- In **Java 8u20**, string de-duplication was implemented. See "[JEP 192: String Deduplication in G1](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/192)".
- In **Java 9**, strings consisting only of LATIN1 characters now store the string using 1 byte per character, instead of 2 bytes per character. See "[JEP 254: Compact Strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254)".

These are all optimization on `String` only. There are likely other memory use improvements, but `String` is the biggest contributor in that area.

Comment: @Bohemian They did say the application was optimized too, so no, not 12 Gb from string optimizations only. I've read about statistics that said in some program more than 50% of memory was consumed by strings. So if we assume a LATIN1 program, then 50% strings * 50% for LATIN1 = 25% savings, of 28Gb = 7 Gb, from strings.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me a good start as to what some of the optimizations could have been.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that there have been significant improvements in Java memory management from v6 to v8?

There have been changes in various aspects of Java that *could* affect the memory usage by an application.  But whether they actually do affect the usage significantly *will depend on the application* ... and they way it was designed and coded, and the way it has been configured / deployed for your environment.

In my opinion<sup>1</sup>, what your vendor is saying is *plausible*, but it is not necessarily true.  The only way to find out if it is true is to *test* the assertion that the (updated) application will work for you with a smaller memory footprint.

And the flipside is that you can't simply push back on the vendor; e.g. saying *"StackOverflow doesn't believe you"*. They will counter with *"where is the concrete evidence"*.  And to get *plausible* evidence ... you need to test.

But here are the real questions:

- If the vendor's assertions are over optimistic, what do you do then?
- Is it your responsibility to fix it, or theirs?  (What do the contracts say?)
- Do you (or they) have a plan for that?
- What happens if the plan fails?
- Can you push back on the "new hardware sizing documents" (if you need to)?

---

<sup>1 - If course, that is just an opinion, and other opinions may differ.  And that is *the real problem here*!</sup>